# Blazor Web Assembly Get User Data from Azure B2C

Tags: blazor-webassembly

using Microsoft Graph i create user and tenant (company from this user, which is saved to a json file and then stored in a container on Azure AD).
I want to display all the information about the user and his company on the screen. The username is already known as:@context.User.Identity?.Name
The name of controller, which have method GetProfile is Tenantcontroller. I tried to make this:

```
<a>@Model.FirmaName</a>  //it's wrong!

@code{

public TenantModel Model { get; set; }

public async Task GetTenantModelTask()
{
    var profile = await PublicClient.GetAll<TenantModel>("tenant/GetAll");
    return    //how to return the value of a variable "profile"?
}
```

}

i know jow it will be in index.html, but index.razor  - this is a catastrophe!! Please!